# How to eliminate 'Email Confirmation' step when using FB auth with ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, facebook-authentication

I'm using ASP.NET Identity in my project. After my user logs in with her FB account she needs to input her email.. I've never met FB auth process that would work like that on any sites but even Microsoft really believes this is necessary is there any easy way to rid of this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property on User called something like "EmailConfirmed". You can set this to true and remove any code for sending confirmation email from the boiler plate code. Email is a required field on the data model though, so FB needs to give you this.